# How to connect AspNetUsers with another table?

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, model, entity

Hi there StackOverflow people.
I currently have a table with clients:

```
 public class Cliente
    {
        public Cliente()
        {
        }

        [Key]
        public int IDCliente { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Morada { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And I have the AspNetUsers table...

[image]

Also, this is my client table data.

[image]

I have that UserName on the table Cliente, and I want to connect it to the aspnetUsers, so that when I create a user, that it will automatically add information between both automatically.
How can that be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize your own UserManager which is inheriting base UserManager , then add Cliente in override CreateUser function implementation.